# Define distribution function on a general measure space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is it possible to define distribution function for a measure on a general measurable space, which generalizes the definition of distribution function for a probability measure on the extended real line?

If yes, how?

If no, how general/special can the measure and the measurable space be in order to define its distribution function?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean Radon-Nikodym?

Comment: I am not quite familiar with Radon-Nikodym, but would like to hear more.

Comment: Generally, the cdf on the line is a "substitute" for a corresponding Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on the line.  Elsewhere we use the measure only.  Even on the line we can use the measure only, now that measure theory is well-known.  Think of the cdf as a way to do things for people who don't know measure theory (either because they are non-mathematicians, beginning mathematicians, or mathematicians from many years ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a well-known definition of cumulative distribution function $F$ for measures on finite dimensional Euclidean space ${\mathbb R}^d$. A function $F$ is the distribution function of a measure on ${\mathbb R}^d$ if and only if $F$ is right continuous and has non-negative increments, where these notions are defined appropriately for multidimensional space.

You can find details about this in Chapter 3 of Olav Kallenberg's *[Foundations of Modern Probability (2nd edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387953132)*, for example.

I'm not aware of useful extensions of the idea of distribution functions to other partially ordered spaces, but they may exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define a measure via a "pullback construction".  Let $(\Omega, {\mathcal S}, \mu)$ be a measure space.  Suppose that $(Y, {\mathcal T})$ is a measurable space and $X: \Omega \rightarrow Y$ be a measurable  function.   You can define a measure $\mu_X$ by 
$$\mu_X(B) = \mu(X^{-1}(B)),  \qquad B\in {\mathcal S}.$$
You can think of $\mu_X$ as being a "distribution measure.  A change of variables formula is not hard to create.